# while running an Espresso test using android studio. I get the following error

Tags: android, compilation, android-espresso

```
Running tests
    Test running started
    java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:166)at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:344)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:38)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.<init>(AndroidJUnit4.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.buildAndroidRunner(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:57)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:45)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runner.C

    omputer.getRunner(Computer.java:38)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:98)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:79)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:26)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.classes(TestRequestBuilder.java:691)
    at 

android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:654)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:329)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:226)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
```

Finish

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this defined in your app/build.gradle but not in global build.gradle

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: not working not a valid module in android studio 3.1.1